# How to: When writing feature file, IDE suggests step definition glue code to use

Tags: cucumber, tdd, serenity-bdd

I am using Serenity Cucumber4, and I am trying to find a way to get prompts when I am writing feature files that can tell me what step definition glue codes are available to me. Otherwise I would do it as I am currently, going into step definition files and copy/pasting the glue code into the feature file.

Is there a plugin for eclipse or vscode? Or maybe a special IDE that has this built it? Or, would I need to create my own plugin for this (I don't know how)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If switching to [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) is an option, there are [plugins](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7212-cucumber-for-java) available to achieve this.

Comment: Do you know if the free version has that plugin?

Comment: @Alex I believe so, last time I used it was using the Community Edition.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! just tried it and it works. This is going to save me so much time.